# How to give the uploaded image file a unique filename

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am running a localhost project. i'm uploading image and some text into localhost phpmysql server. the image file save into `images` folder. when i upload a image called `1.png` its save on the folder as a same name. like this - `images/1.png`.

**what i want -** is it possible to change **automatically** the image file name to a unique one? Like this - `images/1.png` into `images/sgaggjhdzfndzfnd1.png`

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: login.php');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
    }


  // Create database connection
  include_once('db.php');

  // Initialize message variable
  $msg = "";

  // If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get image name
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    // Get text
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);
    
    $text01 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['text01']);
    
    $text02 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['text02']);

    // image file directory
    $target = "images/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text, text01, text02) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text', '$text01', '$text02')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC");
?>
```

Comment: Generate UUID and rename uploaded file.

Comment: I suggest you naming by md5 based on the image size, Or use the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's random functions to create random strings for the uploaded file.

[mt_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

[md5()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

[substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

So, please modify the line:

```
$target = "images/".basename($image);
```

To

```
$target = "images/". substr(md5(mt_rand(0, 9999)), 0, 21) . '-' . basename($image);
```

**Explanation:**

1. You are adding random string to uploaded file using PHP functions.
2. Using random strings to rename/save uploaded files fix a severe issue: An image my get overridden if the same image name's file is uploaded.
3. The uploaded file now has 21 random characters prepended to it. So, there is hardly possibility to have file with same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this it may resolve your issue.

```
$imageName = GetRandomFileName().".".strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $imageName);


public function GetRandomFileName() {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $randomString .= time();
    return $randomString;
}
```